# How to find out if an event in angular 2 is implemented?

Tags: dart, angular

I have this code (angular 2 dart):

```
@Component(
    selector: 'alert',
    events: const ['close'])
@View(
    templateUrl: 'alert.html')
class Alert implements OnInit{
  String type = 'warning';
  EventEmitter close = new EventEmitter();
}
```

How can I find out if the user implemented the `(close)` attribute:

`<alert (close)="closeAlert($event)">Alert!</alert>`

Or find out if the user didn't specify the argument ? I can't check if `close` is null. As this is not the `callback`, but the `EventEmitter` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `close` property does not have to be an `EventEmitter`. You could create a `StreamController` and publish its stream as `close`. `StreamController` has `onListen` property that notifies you when a client attaches to the controller and that's how you would know that a user is listening to the stream. Relying solely on the `(close)` attribute would not be very reliable as your component may be used from an Angular template as well as programmatically.

See: https://api.dartlang.org/1.12.1/dart-async/StreamController/onListen.html

Comment: I've tried it a bit, but it seems like   
```
  Alert() {
    _closeEmitter =
        new StreamController.broadcast(onListen: ()
        => closeable = true);
    close = _closeEmitter.stream;
  }
```
it seems like this onListen event is always fired. I guess angular listens to the stream, without doing anything, even if the user doesn't implement the event callback ?